# Conversion from List<T> to array T[]

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, linq, list

Is there a short way of converting a strongly typed `List<T>` to an Array of the same type, e.g.: `List<MyClass>` to `MyClass[]`?

By short i mean one method call, or at least shorter than:

```
MyClass[] myArray = new MyClass[list.Count];
int i = 0;
foreach (MyClass myClass in list)
{
    myArray[i++] = myClass;
}
```

Answer (score 179, accepted):

Try using

```
MyClass[] myArray = list.ToArray();
```

Comment: That makes a shallow copy, correct? Is unclear from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.toarray?view=net-5.0)...

Answer (score 21):

```
List<int> list = new List<int>();
int[] intList = list.ToArray();
```

is it your solution?

Answer (score 10):

```
list.ToArray()
```

Will do the tric. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/x303t819.aspx) for details.

Answer (score 9):

Use `ToArray()` on `List<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `ToArray()` extension method

Example:

```
Person p1 = new Person() { Name = "Person 1", Age = 27 };
Person p2 = new Person() { Name = "Person 2", Age = 31 };

List<Person> people = new List<Person> { p1, p2 };

var array = people.ToArray();
```

[According to Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.toarray?view=netframework-4.8)

> The elements are copied using `Array.Copy()`, which is an O(n) operation,
>   where n is Count.

Answer (score 0):

To go twice as fast by using multiple processor cores HPCsharp nuget package provides:

```
list.ToArrayPar();
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution to avoid, which uses multiple CPU cores and expected to go faster, yet it performs about 5X slower:

```
list.AsParallel().ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

With the release of C# 12 in .Net 8 (Visual Studio 2022 17.8+), the spread operator (similar to JavaScript) can be used in a collection expression to make a shallow copy of the elements of one collection into another. See more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-12#collection-expressions).

```cs
MyClass[] myArray = [.. list];
```

For the purposes of converting a list to an array, this is semantically equivalent to `list.ToArray()`. However, this syntax can be used with any group of collection types.

```cs
int[] array = [1, 2, 3];
Span<int> span = [4, 5, 6];
List<int> list = [7, 8, 9];
List<int> combined = [.. array, .. span, .. list]; // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```