# How to assign LINQ Query result to Custom Collection and convert List<T> to T[]

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, loops, collections

It's a simple question but i don't really know how to do it efficiently. Is there any way to efficiently convert list of values to array e.g `List<int>` to `int[]` OR `List<CustomObj>` to `CustomObj[]` directly without using loops preferably by using Linq?

In addition, I have a `GenericCollection<T>`, how can i convert the Linq query to `GenericCollection<T>` directly without looping e.g.

```
GenericCollection<T> result = SomeGenericCollection.Select(o => o).ToList<GenericCollection<T>>();
```

Comment: There is a ToArray method that does exactly that: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298736.aspx

Comment: Press `.` on the end of your `List` object and then `CTRL + Space` and it will bring up intellisense for you on the list and you will seek what you wish to achieve - all hail intellisense.

Comment: already this question is there [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/629178/c-sharp-conversion-from-listt-to-array-of-t-t)

Comment: LINQ uses iteration (loops), so you can't avoid looping altogether.

Comment: But i don't wanna use loops to set my GenericCollection<T> after Linq query, Is there any other efficient way to do it.

Comment: @casperOne: What's wrong with Oosterman's answer comparing to 5 another similar? Why have you moved it to comments? I disagree. Also it looks it was the first answer and had more upvotes then all others.

Comment: @abatishchev, its wrong for a concise answer should be punished if it is not lacking in content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the first part of your question, look at the `ToArray()` method as per the other answers:

- `List<T>.ToArray()`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x303t819.aspx
- `Enumerable.ToArray<T>()` extension method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x303t819.aspx#Y0

For the second part, you can write your own extension method:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
   public static GenericCollection<T> ToGenericCollection<T>(
     this IEnumerable<T> input
   )
   {
      // write the conversion here - typically you will need a for loop
   }
}
```

Once you have this, you can convert any collection to your `GenericCollection<T>` as follows:

```
var result = SomeGenericCollection.Select(o => o).ToGenericCollection();
```

You really can't avoid having to write the loop, but this way you only have to write it once.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, though i was using the similar approach. Quite strange if Linq do not provide the way to directly assign result from IEnumerable<T> to GenericCollection<T>, since GenericCollection is deriving from IEnumerable? Can't we just avoid loops without having entension methods of our own?

Comment: @FurqanSafdar you can't avoid loops, no. The for loop may be hidden away in a (framework or custom) method, but it is always there.

Answer (score 2):

Try using Linqs `.ToArray()` method

Answer (score 2):

erm, how about using the [`ToArray()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x303t819.aspx#Y0) Extension Method.

```
var intList = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
int[] intArray = intList.ToArray();
```

---

In answer to the extended question, if `GenericCollection<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>`, and you have a query that returns an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>` or a covariant type like,
`IList<GenericCollection<T>>` you could do,

```
IEnumerable<T> flat = SomeGenericCollectionCollection<T>.SelectMany(o => o)
```

The crux being that `o` is an `IEnumerable<T>` itself.

Comment: @abatishchev, to quell your pedantry, an extension is something that extends. So an Extension Method is an extension to the .Net Framework. I've used the specific proper noun as requested, rather than the generic term.

Comment: Extension Methods are an extension to C#/VB.NET compilers, if you want, being a syntax sugar. But not an extension to .NET Framework.

Answer (score 2):

You simply can use  the `ToArray()` extension method.

Answer (score 1):

Just do like this, use ToArray on the List:

```
List<string> l = new List<string> { "one", "two", "three", "four", "five" };

string[] s = l.ToArray();
```

Comment: I'd prefer to declare `l` with both a meaningful name and as an `IList<string>` or just with `var`.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<int> l = ...
int [] s = l.ToArray()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with [**ToArray()**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x303t819.aspx) linq method.

```
List<int> lst = new List<int>();
int arr[] = lst.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

[`GenericCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee581741.aspx) implements `IEnumerable<T>` so the [`ToArray()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298736.aspx) extension method should work for you.

If not try the following:

```
using System.Linq;

GenericCollection<T> gc = ...
T[] arr = ((IEnumerable<T>)gc).ToArray();
```

or

```
T[] arr = new List<T>(gc).ToArray();
```