# How to convert a list<T> to an array T[] using c#

Tags: c#

I have a list with some 10 records. 
Each record have two values.

```
item->[0] = name:"apple" ,price:10
item->[1] = name:"mango",price :20
```

and so on.

I want to convert this to an array like this.

```
 var items= [
      {name: "apple", price: 10},
      {name: "mango", price: 20},
      /* ... */
    ];
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: There are a similar question, maybe duplicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/629178/conversion-from-listt-to-array-t

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just be able to handle this through LINQ's [`ToArray()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298736(v=vs.100).aspx) method :

```
var array = yourCollectionOfRecords.ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks Rion.. I thought of using .ToArray(), but im not sure if i can get the array as a key value pair just like i mentioned in the question, because i want to use this array in jquery to create a word cloud.

Comment: Create a new class with two properties: `name` and `price`. And then store them in an array.