# How to cast object to List<object> and turn it into an array?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to cast a list to a type, but I am having issues on the following line:

```
value = isArray ? ((List<object>)value).ToArray() : value;
```

I am getting an error saying that it cannot cast **from source type to destination type**. However, If I change `List<object>` to `List<int>` it works. I cannot do that due to the fact that the list most likely won't be an `int` every time since it is dynamic.

Is there an `Invoke` or something that I can do to pass a type as a parameter to say that invoke will return `List<x>` (where `x` is some sort of dynamic type)?

```
var castMethod = this.GetType().GetMethod("CastList").MakeGenericMethod(type);
value = castMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { value });
value = isArray ? ((List<object>)value).ToArray() : value;

public static List<T> CastList<T>(List<object> o) {
    var list = new List<T>();
    foreach (var i in o) { list.Add((T)i); }
    return list;
}
```

In the end the value of `value` will be either a List or an Array.

### Edit

Here is the full method:

```
void SaveDataLocal() {
    keyValues.ForEach(item => {
        var field = GameData.save.GetType().GetField(item.key);
        var value = GetValue(item);
        var isArray = field.FieldType.IsArray;
        var isList = IsList(value);

        // Convert arrays to proper types
        if (isArray || isList) {
            Type type;
            // Get the array type
            if (isArray) type = field.FieldType.GetElementType();
            // Get the list type
            else type = field.FieldType.GetGenericArguments().Single();
            // Do the cast
            var castMethod = this.GetType().GetMethod("CastList").MakeGenericMethod(type);
            value = castMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { value });
            value = isArray ? ((List<object>)value).ToArray() : value;
        }

        field.SetValue(GameData.save, value);
    });
    GameData.Save();
}
```

Here is my key/value object:

```
class KeyValue {
    public string key;
    public object value;

    public KeyValue(string key, object value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Your CastList method very carefully turns a `List<object>` into a `List<T>`, and then you're trying to turn it *back* into a `List<object>` (so back to where you started?), before turning it into an `object[]`?

Comment: Not sure how much you know about unity, but we are making a save data editor, which reads a serialized class, in the class there is fields that will be serialized and saved to disk. In Unity I am making an editor to modify those values without touching the code itself and save it to disk. Those fields can be int's, strings, floats, lists, arrays, etc. When the user changes one it updates the value and saves it to disk. It works with everything currently except for lists due to this casting issue.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question I'm afraid. Why are you carefully converting a `List<object>` into a `List<T>`, then converting it back into a `List<object>` to turn it into an `object[]`? As it stands, I could fix your problem by skipping the whole call to `CastList` and using the original `List<object>` instead. (Helpfully, everything in your question is called `value`, so I can't refer to individual bits of it by name)

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean... `Invoke` returns an `object`, and I can't do `ToArray()` on an object, so I need to cast it somehow, and since it doesn't take a dynamic value, I don't know what else to give it...

Comment: But when you call `castMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { value });`, at that point it casts the `object` to a `List<object>`. So the `object` at that point is actually a `List<object>` underneath. So delete the first and second lines of your question... That gets you *somewhere*: I'm not entirely sure it's where you want to be, but it gets rid of the code that isn't doing anything.

Comment: If I delete those two, I then get this error: `Object type System.Object[] cannot be converted to target type: System.Int32[]` when doing `field.SetValue(GameData.save, value);`

Comment: Right, and that's in some code which isn't in your question.... So it looks like what you really want is an `int[]`. Not an `object[]` (which is what your current code is trying to create). Go back to what you've got now, change `return list` to `return list.ToArray()`, change `public static List<T> CastList<T>` to `public static T[] CastList<T>`, and scrap the casts on line 3.

Comment: That gets you the array side of it sorted. You could also do something like `public static object CastList<T>(List<object> o, bool isArray)` then `return isArray ? list.ToArray() : list`, to handle the list side as well.

Comment: Hmm.... `Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'T[]' and 'System.Collections.Generic.List<T>'`

Comment: Got it! Needed to cast: `return isArray ? (object)list.ToArray() : list;`

Comment: Thanks for the help! If you add an answer I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, what you're actually after is to take a `List<object>` (which each `object` is actually a `T`, and might be a boxed value type), and turn it into either a `List<T>` or a `T[]`, depending on a bool flag.

The easiest thing to do is to modify your CastList method slightly:

```
var castMethod = this.GetType().GetMethod("CastList").MakeGenericMethod(type);
value = castMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { value, isArray });

public static object CastList<T>(List<object> o, bool isArray) {
    var result = o.Cast<T>();
    return isArray ? (object)result.ToArray() : result.ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It seems you don't actually need a `List<>`. You only need an `IEnumerable<>`.

```
(IEnumerable<object>)value).ToArray()
```

Why does that work and `List<>` did not? Because an `IEnumerable<int>` *is* an `IEnumerable<object>`. But a `List<int>` is *not* a `List<object>`, if it were, you could `.Add(new Object())` to said `List<int>`.

Comment: To expand further: this is due to generic variance. `IEnumerable<T>` is covariant (and it is defined as `interface IEnumerable<out T>`), but `List<T>` is not

Comment: hmm... same error still... I am using `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn ah, you're using `int` and `object`. Generic variance only works between reference types. There is simply no way to "cast" a collection containing a value type to any other type of collection. You need to iterate over it and manually convert each element.

Answer (score -3):

Lists are already prepared to work as arrays. If you have:

```
List<object> MyList;
```

Then you can use it as an array. For example:

```
object obj = MyList[2];
```

Comment: Are you sure this is correct? See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/629178/conversion-from-listt-to-array-t)