# Problem with NUnit testing with C# code and test case from file

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

I am C# and NUnit beginner and try to make some simple tests.

When I use hard coded test cases e.g. [TestCase(1, 2)], everything works fine. I would like to use a text file as Test Case source, but don't know how to do. I found some examples on StackOverflow and elsewhere, but it does not work.

```
// Code that works
namespace UnitTesting.GettingStarted.Tests
{

    [TestFixture]

    // this part works fine
    public class CalculatorTestMultiplication
    {
        [TestCase(1, 2)]
        [TestCase(2, 3)]
        [TestCase(3, 8)]
        [TestCase(1000, 1)]

        public void MultiplierParZero(int lhs, int rhs)
        {
            var systemUnderTest = new Calculator();
            Assert.NotZero(systemUnderTest.Multiply(lhs, rhs));

        }
    }
}

//Code with error

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace UnitTesting.GettingStarted.Tests2
{
    public class CalculatorTestMultiplicationFile
    {
        static object[] TestData()
        {
            var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(@"C:\Test\MultiplicationZero.txt"));
            List<object[]> rows = new List<object[]>();

            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                var line = reader.ReadLine();
                var values = line.Split(',');
                rows.Add(values);
            }

            return rows.ToArray<object[]>();   // PROBLEM CODE
        }


        [TestCaseSource("TestCases")]
        public void MultiplyByZero(int lhs, int rhs)
        {

            var systemUnderTest = new Calculator();
            Assert.NotZero(systemUnderTest.Multiply(lhs, rhs));

        }
    }
}
```

As with hard-coded test case, I expect the test to pass if the parameters are not equal to zero, which is what I have in my test file. I cannot even start this test because in the line with the code: "return rows.ToArray();", I see the following error: the non-generic method 'List.ToArray()' cannot be used with type arguments.
Obviously, something is wrong with the object declaration, but I dont`know how to fix it.

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: Use `return rows.ToArray();` duplicate with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/629178/conversion-from-listt-to-array-t

Comment: @Pavel: Thanks, this part is working. Now I have the issue when I run the test because the values are certainly the strings; In the test result I see, for example; MultiplyByZero(7), which means seven tests and in detail ,there is something like MultiplyByZero("1","10"), The test failed although 1*10 should work. My test values should be _int_. So, I tried with 
    `lhs=Convert.ToInt32(lhs);
    rhs=Convert.ToInt32(rhs);` but I still see the same strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a beginner, it's tempting to use simple types and arrays and `object[]` is certainly very simple. However, use of object confuses things a bit, since the error has to do with the Type of the argument. It will be easier if you return an array of `TestCaseData` items, each one of which represents one test case, and deal with a sinngle argument at a time.

For example...

```
static IEnumerable<TestCaseData> TestData()
{
    var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(
        @"C:\Test\MultiplicationZero.txt"));

    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        var line = reader.ReadLine();
        var values = line.Split(',');
        // Assume there are exactly two items, and they are ints
        // If there are less than two or format is incorrect, then
        // you'll get an exception and have to fix the file. 
        // Otherwise add error handling.
        int lhs = Int32.Parse(values[0])
        int rhs = Int32.Parse(values[1]);
        yield return new TestCaseData(lhs, rhs);
    }
}
```

Differences from your code:

1. Use of TestCaseData (not required but I think clearer).
2. Parsing the values as ints. That's the heart of the matter.
3. Returning an enumerable and using `yield` (again, not require but may be clearer)

NOTE: I only typed this in, didn't compile or run. YMMV.

Comment: Great, This works fine with the rest of my code, with the add of semicolon after `int lhs = Int32.Parse(values[0])` to your code :) . Obviously, I can play now and will be able to adapt your code to use any type (string, float...) and add as many parameters as needed . Thanks a lot.