# Unity3D [intermediate] how to convert a List<nodes> .toArray? (pathfinding)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, multidimensional-array, path-finding

**[EDIT] My issue wasn't solve by converting a List .toArray, but you can't find the way to do it in the answer given by @KBaker. Good luck!**

**-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

I've been looking for topics and solutions here and on the Unity website, I didn't find something similar to my issue and am struggling since two weeks so please don't score this topic down for free. **Thank you in advance!**

As you can see on the following picture, my unit has orthogonal-only movements:

[image: pathExample]

That comes from `SymplifyPath()` in my Pathfinding script:

```
IEnumerator FindPath(Vector3 startPos, Vector3 targetPos){
    Vector3[] finalPath = new Vector3[0];
    bool pathSuccess = false;
    [...]//body
    yield return null;
    if (pathSuccess){
        finalPath = RetracePath(startNode, targetNode);
    }
    pathQueue.FinishedProcessingPath(finalPath, pathSuccess);
}

Vector3[] RetracePath(Nodes startNode, Nodes endNode){
    List<Node> path = new List<Node>();
    Node currentNode = endNode;
    while (currentNode != startNode){
        path.Add(currentNode);
        currentNode = currentNode.parent;
    }
    Vector3[] finalPath = SymplifyPath(path);
    Array.Reverse(finalPath);
    return finalPath;
}

Vector3[] SymplifyPath(List<Nodes> path){
    List<Vector3> finalPath = new List<Vector3>();
    Vector2 directionOld = Vector2.zero;
    for(int i = 1; i < path.Count; i++){
        Vector2 directionNew = new Vector2(path[i - 1].gridX - path[i].gridX, path[i - 1].gridZ - path[i].gridZ);{
            finalPath.Add(path[i - 1].worldPosition);
        }
        directionOld = directionNew;
    }
    return finalPath.ToArray();
}
```

In the line `waypoints.Add(path[i - 1].worldPosition);`, having `-1` makes orthogonal-only movements. Without `-1`, paths have smoother movements but its path doesn't care about the middle of each nodes anymore and goes through walls. Without `SimplyPath()`, the original path cares about diagonals, middle of nodes and doesn't go through walls. That's exactly what I'm looking for.

Is it possible to use `SimplifyPath()` to convert the list of nodes located in `RetracePath` to arrays, without creating a new simplified path?

I'm thinking about something like:

```
Vector3[] SymplifyPath(List<Nodes> path){
    List<Vector3> finalPath = new List<Vector3>();
    Vector2 nodesListPath = Vector2.zero;
    for(int i = 1; i < path.Count; i++)
        {
            finalPath(path[i].worldPosition)
        }
        finalPath = nodesListPath;
    }
    return finalPath.ToArray();
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check out [this website](https://www.dotnetperls.com/convert-list-array) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/629178/conversion-from-listt-to-array-t) to convert your list to an array.

Comment: I'll try it now, hoping that works, thank you again for answering ;)